# Clean Uninstallation of Python Packages after Ubuntu Upgrade

Tags: python, ubuntu

I recently upgraded a machine from Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS using command line. As a result, the built-in Python installation is upgraded from Python 3.5 to 3.6. And it seems that all the Python packages previously installed using `pip3` are no longer accessible. I plan to clean up all those packages and use `conda` for Python package management. My question is, **what is the best practice for a clean uninstallation of those inaccessible packages in this case**?

The old packages installed via `pip3` were primarily located under `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/` and `~/.local/lib/python3.5/`. But there could be other leftover files, e.g., under `/usr/local/bin/`. I would like to remove all of related files that came with `pip3 install`.

Comment: if you are sure that they are not used by system then delete them as any other file - `rm filename`.

Comment: The packages can neither be accessed in the code nor via `pip3` commands. The problem is that I am not sure where all the related files can be located besides the common directories.

Comment: if you still can run command `python3.5` then you can run old python to display `sys.path`. There are folders which Python uses to search modules.

Comment: if you can run `python3.5` then maybe you have still `pip3.5` or you can use `python3.5 -m pip`

Comment: I can't run `python3.5`. I am considering the possibility of temporarily installing `python3.5` or finding another way for `pip3` to recognize the packages for `python3.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a bash script to call `pip3 uninstall` on each previously installed package iteratively.

```
#!/bin/bash

pypath_cmd="PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages"
export $pypath_cmd
echo "Uninstalling editable packages in $PYTHONPATH"
rm -f $PYTHONPATH/*.egg-link
rm -f $PYTHONPATH/easy-install.pth

pip3 freeze --all --local | cut --delimiter="=" -f 1 | while read pkg ; do
    echo $pkg: $(pip3 show $pkg | grep "Location:")
    pip3 uninstall -y $pkg
done

pypath_cmd="PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages"
export $pypath_cmd
echo "Uninstalling editable packages in $PYTHONPATH"
sudo rm -f $PYTHONPATH/*.egg-link
sudo rm -f $PYTHONPATH/easy-install.pth

pip3 freeze --all --local | cut --delimiter="=" -f 1 | while read pkg ; do
    echo $pkg: $(pip3 show $pkg | grep "Location:")
    sudo $pypath_cmd pip3 uninstall -y --no-cache-dir $pkg
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo pip install` installs pip packages to`/usr/local/lib/<python_version>/dist-packages`, and apt packages to `/usr/lib/<python_version>/dist-packages`. Check these directories and remove the unwanted packages.

Comment: As I mentioned in the second paragraph of the question, there could still be files left over in other places besides the package folders. I hope that those files could be removed as well.